# Data not showing in tables, only column names

Tags: sql

I am trying to join my tables however the query only returns the column names without the data. Here is my query:

```
SELECT SUM(s.CurrentValue*hr.Shares) AS 'Total Assests Under Mangement for ClientId: 3', cl.ClientName
From Stocks s 
JOIN HoldingReport hr
    ON s.stocksId = hr.stocksId
JOIN Clients cl
    ON s.stocksId = cl.ClientId
Where hr.ClientId = 3
group by ClientName
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: `s.stocksId = cl.ClientId` are you sure this is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is highly suspicious:

```
SELECT SUM(s.CurrentValue*hr.Shares) AS total_assets, cl.ClientName
FROM Stocks s JOIN
     HoldingReport hr
     ON s.stocksId = hr.stocksId JOIN
     Clients cl
     ON s.stocksId = cl.ClientId
--------^ ???
WHERE hr.ClientId = 3
GROUP BY ClientName;
```

I would expect the condition to be `s.ClientId = cl.ClientId`.

Note:  I strongly discourage you from using single quotes for column aliases.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.